# Speed up replications of confidence intervals

Tags: r, performance, replication, confidence-interval

I am trying to speed up the calculation of confidence intervals based on the coefficients from a regression model run many times. I wonder if there is a way to improve the performance. Here is the code close to what I want to achieve. Running this doesn't take much time but I have a larger dataset and it has been running almost a day without yet getting the result.

```
#Sample some cases and run regression model
regfun <- function(x=mtcars) {
  take.smp <- sample(nrow(x),10,replace=TRUE)
  smp <- x[unlist(take.smp),]
  mod <- lm(smp[[1]]~ smp[[2]] + smp[[3]] + smp[[4]])
  coef(mod)
}

#Repeat the regression model to get more coefficients
repcoef <- function() t(replicate(2000, regfun()))

#Generate more replications based on the repeated coefficient function 
#to get reliable confidence intervals 
repci <- replicate(1000,t(apply(repcoef(), 2, quantile, probs=c(.025,.975), na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Did you notice that with `1:length(x)` you're sampling the columns instead of rows as probably intended? You probably want `1:nrow(x)` or short `nrow(x)`.

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks for pointing that out. I just edited it.

Comment: @jay.sf It appears that for this example `.lm.fit` and `lm.fit` gave the same results: `set.seed(745)
take.smp <- sample(nrow(mtcars), 10, replace=TRUE)
smp <- mtcars[take.smp, ]
mod1 <- lm.fit(model.matrix(~ smp[[2]] + smp[[3]] + smp[[4]]), smp[[1]])
mod1$coefficients
mod2 <- .lm.fit(model.matrix(~ smp[[2]] + smp[[3]] + smp[[4]]), smp[[1]])
mod2$coefficients`. `.lm.fit` is faster because it does not rearrange the coefficients but rather return the pivoting vector and a flag indicating if coefficient rearrangement is needed

Comment: That's right, I'm not exactly sure what's you're point now, though. Anyway at the bottom of [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/qraux.html) there's an example that pivotes, you may put it into `lm.fit` and `.lm.fit` for testing. I'm not sure when exactly pivoting happens (despite of the why), but it happens and I strongly recommend to sort always the output according to the vector using `mod$coefficients[sort.list(mod$pivot)]`. I've benchmarked with `if (pivoted)` but case handling was slower than sorting at once.

Comment: @jay.sf I am not an expert on linear algebra but it seems that pivoting helps deliver a pure and simple matrix to solve the equation system (or otherwise no solution at all). It can also let collinearity problem emerge if it exists (see https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/pivot.html). To your point of sorting the pivoting vector, I agree it is a good practice against messy results

Comment: You're digging into the _why_, nice. Yes, pivoting has computational advantages and can deal better with near-rankdeficient matrices. Howsoever, sorting the coefficients using `sort.list(mod$pivot)`  it is mandatory when using `.lm.fit` in contrast to `lm.fit`. Nevertheless it is still faster than `lm.fit` because this does even more stuff than just resorting and thus has additional overhead.

Comment: Hi @jay.sf, hope you are doing well! Lately I have been working on this with a larger dataset but even with the use of `.lm.fit` or `lm.fit` it still takes several days to complete. Do you have any knowledge of `c++` or maybe the `Rcpp` package in R? I am sure doing using `c++` will be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lm.fit` instead of `lm` in this way:

```
regfun2 <- function(x = mtcars) {
  take.smp <- sample(1:length(x), 10, replace=TRUE)
  smp <- x[unlist(take.smp), ] # NB: `unlist` is not necessary
  mod <- lm.fit(model.matrix(~ smp[[2]] + smp[[3]] + smp[[4]]), smp[[1]])
  mod$coefficients
}
```

This is faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  lm = regfun(),
  lm.fit = regfun2(),
  times = 100
)
Unit: microseconds
   expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
     lm 1323.168 1412.1260 1750.011 1668.2765 1916.277 2946.757   100   b
 lm.fit  786.764  855.1195 1030.725  948.5295 1112.704 1914.135   100  a
```

Comment: Any reason for `lm.fit` and not the faster `.lm.fit`?

Comment: @jay.sf What's the difference between `lm.fit` and `.lm.fit`? To me, if you set `method = "qr"` in `lm.fit`, that will be `.lm.fit`. Am I right?

Comment: Also, I meant to say thank you @Stéphane Laurent for your code and suggestion!

Comment: @cliu `.lm.fit` calls [C_Cdqrls](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/lm.c), (the actual C function that computes (using Fortran) the linear regression), directly, whereas `lm.fit` does some other stuff (like de-pivoting), which you probably don't need. Just type `lm.fit` and `.lm.fit` into the console (without `?` or parentheses) to compare. Note that you'd have to use `mod$coefficients[sort.list(mod$pivot)]` with `.lm.fit` to account for [pivoting](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/qraux.html).